# Maximizing nth largest element of grid

Tags: z3, z3py

I've got a numpy array (48 x 3) of IntVectors (`X`) where various subsections of this array have constraints. I also have a (48 x 1) of pre-defined integer constants (`initial_scores`).

Given these constraints I'd like to maximize for the 13th largest possible row-sum; that is if we took `[initial_scores[k] + X[k, 0] + X[k, 1] + X[k, 2] for k in range(48)]`, sorted it (descending) and returned the 13th element.

In some literature I came across the `nth` and a `mk_seq_nth` function but neither are defined functions so I'm likely not using them correctly, or perhaps they're not available in z3py?

Here's a [gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/Noxville/a55c76c7631a3f31344802aec7143cd3) (69 LOC).

Answer (score 1):

For stack-overflow, it's best to minimize your example and ask specific questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Having said that, the following might get you started. Sorting a list of numbers in z3 is both dead-simple since we can simply assert the result must be sorted, and also tricky due to handling possible replications. The following routine achieves this by indexing the incoming elements, and making sure they are all present in the output:

```py
from z3 import *

# sort ascending
def z3Sort(s, lst):
    n = len(lst)

    # indexed result
    res = [(FreshInt(), FreshInt()) for i in range(n)]

    # assert that result is sorted on the values
    for i in range(n-1):
        s.add(res[i][1] <= res[i+1][1])

    # assert that each element in the list is somewhere in the result
    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        isIn = False
        for j, k in res:
            isIn = Or(isIn, And(i == j, e == k))
        s.add(isIn)

    # return the sorted list
    return [e[1] for e in res]
```

Note how we allocate two fresh variables (`FreshInt`) for each index, assert that the result is sorted on values, and then ensure that each element of the incoming list is present somewhere in this list.

Note that this sorts ascending. You can modify it to make it go descending.

With this helper routine, let's solve a problem that sounds like what you are describing. Let's say we have a list with some constraints, constants/symbolics etc:

```py
x, y = Ints('x y')
lst = [IntVal(12), 3+x, 1+y, IntVal(7)]
o.add(sum(lst) == 20)
```

Let's maximize the 3rd element of the sorted-list:

```
sortedLst = z3Sort(o, lst)
o.maximize(sortedLst[2])
```

Now we can ask z3 for our results:

```py
r = o.check()
if r == sat:
    m = o.model()
    print("x     : ", m.evaluate(x, model_completion = True))
    print("y     : ", m.evaluate(y, model_completion = True))
    print("Input : ", [m.evaluate(e, model_completion = True) for e in lst])
    print("Output: ", [m.evaluate(e, model_completion = True) for e in sortedLst])
else:
    print("Solver said: " + str(r))
```

This prints:

```py
x     :  9
y     :  -12
Input :  [12, 12, -11, 7]
Output:  [-11, 7, 12, 12]
```

You can convince yourself that this is the best you can do under the given constraints. (Think about how x and y must change with respect to each other to maximize the third element of the output.)

Hopefully you can take this sample and adapt it to your own problem.